# (Sublime Text 3) bash: javac: command not found

Tags: java, sublimetext3, sublimetext, javac

I'm trying to get a working build system for Java on Sublime Text 3, but whenever I try to run anything, i just get `bash: javac: command not found.`

The strangest thing about this is that I can run the javac command from a terminal, as I have added the line

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk && export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

to the .bashrc file in my home directory.

So I have no idea why I can run Java files using javac and java from the terminal, however Sublime Text cannot.

Here is what I have for my build system:

```
{
   "shell_cmd": "javac \"$file_name\" && java \"$file_base_name\"",
   "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
   "selector": "source.java",
}
```

I am using Manjaro 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are using Manjaro, which is Arch derivative; instead of setting the `JAVA_HOME` variable, you should use `archlinux-java` to set the default JDK version.
`archlinux-java` is part of `java-runtime-common` package.

---

When something is wrong, Sublime will print your current path variable ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mewFX.png)). Make sure the paths are set correctly.

I tried your build system on my Arch machine, and it is working correctly, I also tried setting the `JAVA_HOME` variable, and it is still working.

Using Sublime Text 3 Build 3211

Comment: Thank you, I managed to fix it by specifying the path variable in the build system as for some reason Sublime wasn't using the global one (I could tell because when I ran it from terminal it worked).

Answer (score 0):

For future users with the same issue, I solved it by specifying the path variable in my build system by adding:

```
"path":"your/directory/here"
```

The whole thing where I added the line to .bashrc turned out to be completely unnecessary, as this fixed it.